# "Realm accessed from incorrect thread" when changing objects after receiving HTTP response

Tags: ios, swift, multithreading, realm

I'm making a server request using `NSURLSession`, and when a response is received I make a UI change on the main thread using:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue())
```

But I'm currently getting the error:

> libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type `realm::IncorrectThreadException`: Realm accessed from incorrect thread.

I already tried to make the changes (saving the object) on the main thread, and on the background thread, but I get always the same error. Is there any way to know which thread is being accessed by Realm?

**EDIT:**

After perform save, and query on the main_thread, the error dont occur anymore, 
but now, if i print the object the values are correct, but when i runit, all the values are null,  `<uninitialized>`

Answer (score 1):

Realm's `IncorrectThreadException` tells you that you're accessing a Realm object from a thread other than the one it was created on. Looking up the stack from the point where this exception is thrown will reveal which object you're accessing. A [C++ exception breakpoint in Xcode](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-breakpoint_navigator/articles/adding_an_exception_breakpoint.html) can be helpful for this purpose. Hopefully it should be clear from what your code is doing which thread the object is *supposed* to be executing on.

Comment: Well, i cant see clearly wich thread i am, on the save. I tried to use ```Realm().refresh()``` so the value is updated when i need it, but some properties are ```<uninitialized>``` when i try to acess it, even tough on the debugPrint the values are correct, and the po gives me the correct values. Any todds on this?

Comment: How are you checking the property values such that you're seeing `<uninitialized>`?